# A tool to check a Wi-Fi connection

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, wireless-networking

I'm having a lot of problems connecting to [Eduroam](https://cat.eduroam.org/) Wi-Fi network using Windows 10.

My problem is that Windows 10 doesn't offer any error message about what is is happening.

My user and password is correct but, when I try to connect Windows is always asking me about my user and password. And, sometimes, it doesn't ask anything: I only see under the network's name "Connecting" or "Secure network".

I have tried with an old MacBook and I get the error: "authentication service is not responding"

Is there any Windows 10 tool to know what it is happening when I try to connect to this network? (Or maybe you know what is happening).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually sounds like a problem with the infrastructure – it usually happens when the Wi-Fi access point cannot reach the authentication server. Eduroam uses WPA-Enterprise, and the Wi-Fi APs do not process your password directly but instead relay it to the institution's central RADIUS server, then send the response back. It is very possible that one of the nearby APs has lost its wired connection to the institution network but continues to broadcast a (strong but useless) Wi-Fi signal and keeps getting chosen by your computers as the preferred AP.

Talk to whoever is managing the Eduroam Wi-Fi hardware at your location.

Additionally, if you're not at your home institution (that is, if the "@realm" in your username is different than where you're connecting), it could also be a problem with the connection between the two institutions. (Make sure you *do* add the @domain suffix to the username, as some sites deliberately reject Eduroam logins without one.)

If you had a Linux system, Wireshark would be able to show the 'EAPOL' packets being exchanged over the Wi-Fi adapter during authentication, but it probably wouldn't reveal a lot. As this doesn't need "monitor mode" it *might* also work with Wireshark on Windows and/or macOS as well.